# SQL Query to return both distinct and total logins from a login table in sql2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table Logins { Id, AccessTime }, I'd like to write a query that returns 3 columns, Total Logins during a time period, Unique Logins for a time period, and the Id of the user.

I know I could do this with two passes and a join, is there a better way to do it in a single pass?

Thanks,
~Prescott

Edit: After considering this futher, if they they show up at all, then they are a unique login, thus I can just grab count(*), userId group by userid.

Sorry for the sillyness.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between Total Logins and Unique Logins. You say you want the id of the user, so I assume this query is supposed to return a result for each user for a given time period. I assume the start and end date are parameters to your query?

Comment: following on from dcp. Do you mean total for all users? Or unique users per time period?

Comment: Post your answer and then when the 2 day wait period goes by accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poorly thought out before asking this question, essentially, if they have a record in the date period for Count(*), then their unique login is 1..